# $\int_\gamma\frac{1}{\sqrt z}dz$ where $\gamma$ is the lower half of the unit circle from $+1$ to $-1$

Tags: complex-analysis

To solve this I put $\gamma(t)=e^{-it}$ with $t\in(0,\pi)$. Then
$$
\int_\gamma z^{-\frac{1}{2}}dz=-\int_0^\pi e^{\frac{it}{2}}ie^{-it}dt=-i\int_0^\pi e^{-\frac{it}{2}}dt=2(e^{i\pi/2}-e^{0})=-2-2i.
$$
But if I use $\sigma(t)=e^{it}$, $t\in(\pi,2\pi)$, then
$$
\int_\gamma z^{-\frac{1}{2}}dz=-\int_\sigma z^{-\frac{1}{2}}dz=-\int_\pi^{2\pi}e^{-\frac{it}{2}}ie^{it}dt=-i\int_\pi^{2\pi}e^{\frac{it}{2}}dt=-2(e^{\pi i}-e^\frac{\pi i}{2})=2+2i.
$$

I cant see where is the problem. I'll thank you for any help.

Comment: You have to select a branch of $\sqrt{z}$ in order for this problem to be well-defined. Without doing that, these are both valid answers in the sense that they correspond to choosing the same branch of $\sqrt{z}$ along the entire path.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. If I take $\sqrt(z)=|z|^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{i\theta/2}$, $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi]$, then the first solution is correct and the second one fails.?? I'm confused with the branches.

Comment: I assume you mean $|z|^{1/2} e^{i\theta/2}$ where $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi]$. And then I think the first one is what you have.

Comment: To define the problem in the first place, it is necessary to not only specify the *set of points*  over which you are integrating, but also the direction over which it is being integrated (clockwise or counterclockwise in this case). As well as the branch. You may as well see what the answer is for both branches, since there are only two of them.

Comment: Oh yeah, this not only has the issue of the branch but also the issue of the direction, since the first one goes clockwise and the second goes counterclockwise. So actually the first parametrization is correct for the way the problem is stated, and the question is just whether this is the branch of $\sqrt{z}$ that you want (which it probably is, since this is the branch that is positive on the positive real axis).

Comment: Thanks to all. I think I understand, in the second, I am integrating into the other branch and that is why it gives the opposite result.

Answer (score 1):

Reversing the direction of the contour, flips the sign of your result.

Indeed, the parametrisation $\sigma(t)=e^{it}$, $t\in(\pi,2\pi)$ is the lower half of the unit circle from $\color{red}{-}1$ to $\color{red}{+}1$